# How to NOT print some of the sections in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

So basically I want to create a Table of Contents in my latex document (class - article). But I don't want the first half sections to be printed. For examples, suppose there are four sections in my document - Section 1, Section 2, Section 3 and Section 4. Then I want my TOC to look like this

1. Section 3 -- pagenumber
2. Section 4 -- pagenumber

While I want to retain the section number and names in the main text.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\section*{First section}` etc should do for not appearing in the TOC.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the request, there are some possibilities:

`\section*{Title}` ---> No toc entry at all

`\section[]{Title}` ----> No toc entry, but numbered section

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section*{First -- not in TOC}%
\blindtext
\section*{Second -- not in TOC too}%
\blindtext
\section{Third}%
\blindtext
\section{Fourth}%
\blindtext
\section[]{Fifth}%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer works with the "scrartcl" class, but not (for me) with the "article" or "amsart" classes.  With "article", `\section*` is left out of the TOC while `\section[]` inserts a blank but numbered line into the TOC, while with "amsart" all three commands add TOC entries (with `\section*` being an unnumbered entry and the other two numbered).

Comment: @MikeShulman: Yes? What's your addition to this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I was pointing out that your answer only works with a particular document class (which happens not to be the one the OP said he was using).

Comment: @MikeShulman: I never claimed it would work with other classes

Comment: Sure. But since you didn't actually mention document classes at all, I spent a while being confused about why your solution didn't work for me, until I realized it depended on the document class. So I thought I would spare other readers that wasted time.

Comment: @MikeShulman: Right, I will change it. Perhaps I had that in mind already one year ago, but there was no reaction by the O.P. so I came never back to it (unfortunately)